# how to delete an entity with blobkeys from google app engine datastore

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

What's the best practice for deleting an ndb entity that contains blob keys?

Should I wrap this in a try catch? Can I flatten the for loop into a batch (though ndb is asnyc)?

This is what I've tried so far but i'm not sure if it's the best way:

```
to_delete = BlogPost.query(ancestor=ndb.Key('BlogPost', int(id))).fetch(1)[0]
for blob_key in to_delete.blob_keys:
    info = blobstore.BlobInfo(bob_key)
    info.delete()
to_delete.key.delete()
delete_success = "successfully deleted"

self.response.out.write(delete_success)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you should delete the blobs in a task instead of inline with the entity itself.
You can create a transaction that will queue the task and delete the entity at once.

Deleting the blobs in a task will give you the benefit of retries in case of an error and it will no delay the delete operation in case you have a lot of blobs.

Comment: Ok thanks - I forgot about those for a second. This is the doc right? https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/overview